# Skip before_filter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, before-filter

Names and objects have been simplified for clarity's sake. The basic concept remains the same.

I have three controllers: `dog`, `cat`, and `horse`.
These controllers all inherit from the controller `animal`.
In the controller `animal`, I have a before filter that authenticates a user as such:

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |name, password|
    name == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
end
```

In the `show` action of `dog`, I need to have open access to all users (skip the authentication).

If I were to write the authentication separately for `dog`, I could do something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :except => :show
```

But since `dog` inherits from `animal`, I do not have access to the controller-specific actions. Adding `:except => :show` in the `animal` controller will not only skip authentication for the `show` action of `dog`, but also that of `cat` and `horse`. This behaviour is not desired.

How can I skip the authentication only for the `show` action of `dog` while still inheriting from `animal`?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
class Dog < Animal
  skip_before_filter :authenticate, :only => :show
end
```

See [ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) for more info on filters and inheritance.

Comment: `skip_before_filter` seems to be deprecated >> [http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter#1083-deprecated-moved](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter#1083-deprecated-moved) They recommand to use `skip_filter` which is calling `skip_before_filter`, `skip_after_filter` and `skip_around_filter` all together.

Comment: no is not.. they just move the method to another class, http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter

Answer (score 12):

The two answers given are half right. In order to avoid making all your dog actions open, you need to qualify the skip_before_filter to only apply to the 'show' action as follows:

```
class Dog < Animal
  skip_before_filter :authenticate, :only => :show
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you can use skip_before_filter

It's explained in the [Rails API](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

In your example `dog`just would have to contain

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small update that using rails 4, it is now `skip_before_action :authenticate, :only => :show` and that before_filters should now use `before_action` instead.

Comment: This should be a comment.