# How to set a before_filter for every controller bar one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, before-filter

In Ruby on Rails, I would like to add a before_filter to every controller except for one.  Currently I have in `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :authenticate
```

Is there a way to apply this rule inside `ApplicationController` rather than adding `before_filter :authenticate` in every controller *except* the public controller?

Comment: Duplicate of [Skip before_filter in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390178/skip-before-filter-in-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the before filter in `ApplicationController` and then skip it in the controller where you don't want it:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run this filter in every controller but one, why not simply skip it?

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate
end
```

If you want to skip a particular action, you can use `:except`:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :except => [ :index ]
```