# how to redirect users after login? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

When a user logs in, they automatically get routed to the /user page for example. 
How can I have them directed to the main homepage (home.htm.erb) after logging in?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640326/redirect-user-after-log-in-only-if-its-on-root-path

Comment: this actually depends on your code.  are you using some sort of authentication gem like devise or omniauth?  or did you roll out your own?  you need to include those details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a Sessions object you're creating?  In the `sessions#create` action

```
redirect_to root_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your gem for authentication

In your app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController  'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
end
```