# Redirect root_path in rails for already signed_in user without using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

In my application i have **root_path** `root 'home#mainPage'` and though a user is signed in , he can accesss `http://localhost:3000/` which i dont want. So i am following https://stackoverflow.com/a/8739874/3786657 answer to add this feature and i am getting `undefined method user_signed_in? for AuthenticatedUser:Class`. I am using Rails 4.2.0

**My routes:**

```
  constraints(AuthenticatedUser) do 
    root :to => "users#show", as: :authenticated
  end

  root 'home#mainPage'
```

**Lib/authenticated_user.rb:**

```
class AuthenticatedUser
  def self.matches?(request)
    user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def user_signed_in?
        !!session[:user_id]
    end
    def current_user
        User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
end
```

**Config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `user_signed_in?` method defined in `ApplicationHelper` is not available to `AuthenticatedUser`. Since you can get the session from the request I would just check it directly in `AuthenticatedUser`:

```
class AuthenticatedUser
  def self.matches?(request)
    !!request.session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: its saying `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` now

Comment: Its occuring Users controller `# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: It looks like whatever page you're hitting does not set params[:id] to a valid user id...

Comment: actually, using `!!request.session[:user_id]`, id is passing as nil

Comment: There is no `id` in that expression.

Comment: With `!!request.session[:user_id]` its redirecting to `users#show` but failing..any solution or any other workaround ?

Comment: `def set_user @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) end` instead of using the params should work, but only if the logged in user will be the only person ever accessing that page. If its a public page that others can go to, that won't work.

Comment: any way to access helper method in lib directory ?