# Application Controller level validation with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm not sure what is the best way to make sure that every user has some necessary attributes, and if they don't i would like to redirect them to 'new' page e.g.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :valid_location

  def valid_location
    if (current_user.location.nil? || current_user.location.city.nil?)
      redirect_to new_user_locations_path(current_user.id)
     else
       true
    end
end
```

The above example is flawed because it creates a redirect loop. I could definetelly use some advice on creating this sort of validation. Thank you

Comment: in the locations controller, just add `skip_before_filter :valid_location, only: :new` to fix the redirect loop.  and also, you dont need to return true so just remove the else part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is creating a redirect loop is because the `valid_location` method is also being called on the controller responsible for the `new_user_locations_path`. To prevent this you need to make sure that controller does not run that filter with [skip_before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter) (`skip_before_action` in Rails 4). A similar issue has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390178/skip-before-filter-in-rails).

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :valid_location, only: [:new, :create]
  #...
end
```

Because `valid_location` returns a true/false boolean, I would recommend renaming the method to `valid_location?` or `invalid_location?` and refactoring the logic a little:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :redirect_invalid_locations

  private
  def redirect_invalid_locations
    redirect_to(new_user_locations_path(current_user)) if invalid_location?
  end

  def invalid_location?
    current_user.try(:location).try(:city).nil?
  end
end


class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :redirect_invalid_locations, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Comment: THank you very much. there is only one small thing that I had to change. added :create to: skip_before_filter :redirect_invalid_locations, only: [:new, :create] otherwise i was getting: Filter chain halted as :redirect_invalid_locations rendered or redirected