# authenticate_user! for all but a single page -- how to do that easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use `authenticate_user!` in all, but a single page "login" page, in my Rails application. For this I can insert `authenticate_user!` in all the controllers. But it'd be easier to insert it into `ApplicationController` and
disabe only on "login" page or rather in SessionController for "login" action. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip before\_filter in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390178/skip-before-filter-in-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do.,

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

And you can mention the methods you want to exclude using `except:`.

Comment: will I have to override the SessionsController of devise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595298/skip-before-filter-for-the-login-action-of-devise