# skip_before_filter for the "login" action of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I can do this to skip calling "authenticate_user" in a certain controller where I need to:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

I want to call `skip_before_filter` for "login" action of devise gem and I don't want to have to override anything else. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to override devise sessions controler:

**1)** create a `users/sessions_controller.rb` file:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

**2)** and set it on `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`skip_before_filter` is deprecated, so try to `use skip_before_action`

it's worked with me